# I actually reset the MDT keys on my Coral Dev board but not it doesn't let me access the board

Tags: google-coral

I get the following error when I use "mdt shell".
I have went through the documentation and all I want to know how I can access the board files? As the documentation tells me to remove the authorized keys from /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized-keys directory.
I have connected the serial port but I don't see anything when I try to Dmesg| grep but i get a sound like a device is connected to the PC. How can I access the coral files in order to delete the authorized files?
I'm using UBUNTU terminal on Windows.

'''
~$ mdt shell green-horse
Waiting for device green-horse...
Connecting to green-horse at 192.168.101.2
Key not present on green-horse -- pushing

Couldn't connect to keymaster on green-horse: [Errno 111] Connection refused.

Did you previously connect from a different machine? If so,
mdt-keymaster will not be running as it only accepts a single key.

You will need to either:

1. Remove the key from /home/mendel/.ssh/authorized_keys on the
   device via the serial console

- or -

  2. Copy the mdt private key from your home directory on this host
     in ~/.config/mdt/keys/mdt.key to the first machine and use
     'mdt pushkey mdt.key' to add that key to the device's
     authorized_keys file.

Failed to push via keymaster -- will attempt password login as a fallback.
Can't login using default credentials: Bad authentication type; allowed types: ['publickey']
'''

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu terminal on a Virtual Machine ? Virtual Machines don't get unrestricted access to USB ports sometimes. Please check in your VM settings if the USB ports are enabled.

Comment: Once you are able to run the screen command, You can ssh into the board using wifi. Connect the board using "screen" command. 

You can then copy the public key from your host machine ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and put it in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the dev board.

Then you should be able to ssh with just:

$ ssh mendel@(IP Address of the board)

The board's ip address can be found under wlan/eth (If board is connected to wifi/ethernet) interface of the ip addr command.

Comment: Another way to get into a Mendel shell is to connect a USB mouse and keyboard to the Dev Board, and attach an HDMI monitor.  After the boot sequence, the GUI appears.  Click the icon in the upper-left corner of the GUI display and a shell will appear.  Then you can remove the key.  Then you can get MDT shell working with your new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you insert the SD card on the first attempt to connect using mdt?
If so, remove it and try again.